# What program to use to visualise neural network diagram and math functions

Tags: neural-network

I am writing a paper about machine learning and I need to create some neural network diagrams and basic math functions I am describing. I need a program to create visually decent technical picture without spending days to learn how to use the program.

Comment: Use LateX, it's so convenient.

Comment: Do the maths in LaTeX or something like Markdown that can be converted to it. For the diagrams see 1) https://github.com/gwding/draw_convnet 2) https://github.com/battlesnake/neural 3) http://daft-pgm.org

Comment: I am using LaTex, so there is a package to visualise functions? thanks!

Comment: Yes, [tikz](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/plots/)

Answer (score 0):

[alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/](https://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/) works well for neural network visualization.

[LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/) is the standard for visualizing math.